# Can't authenticate user using React and Spring Security

Tags: spring, reactjs, security, authentication

i am trying to login to my app via front written in React. The method which is responsible for form login. Button invoke this method:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        PostData('perform_login', this.state).then((result) => {
          let responseJSON = result;
      console.log(responseJSON);
    });
  }
```

And this is a Data with username and password

```
export function PostData(type, userData) {

  let BaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(BaseUrl + type, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      resolve(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

I am trying to log in to backend, spring config looks like that:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
          .cors()
        .and()
          .csrf().disable()
          .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*", "/success*").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**", "/css/*", "/webjars/**","/js/*","/image/*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin()
          .successHandler(mySuccessHandler)
          .failureHandler(myFailureHandler)
          .loginProcessingUrl("perform_login")
          .usernameParameter("username")
          .passwordParameter("password")
          .successForwardUrl("/tasks")
        .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll()
        .and()
          .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
  }
```

Important line in this file i think is the loginProcessingUrl("perform_login") which i used to verify my username and password from react.

While i do something like that in CURL is working fine:

```
curl -i -X POST -d username=admin -d password=admin http://localhost:8080/perform_login
```

But if i want authenticate by Postman or React it doesn't work, please about help/hints
Regards

Comment: Your backend security config seams to be ok ! Try to have a look to this article [Spring security + React](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-react)

Comment: yes, i fix it, but i have a next question, how can i store my session id, because i need this for communication right? For example i want to get some data from my server

Comment: It depends on your choice and your implementations, for me I prefer to use token strategy via JWT or OAuth2 and avoid many security risk. But if you want to use session you should configure it ( by controlling the sessionManagement part `http.sessionManagement().xxx()` ). You can have a look at this [Spring Security Session](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

Comment: Feel free to post me a message If you want to have some examples of JWT + Spring Security

Comment: Yes sure, i don't know what is JWT yet but can you give me example of it? or Maybe OAuth, i don't know what is better?

Comment: JWT and OAuth are token based security, they are stateless by nature and represent the user claims, so instead of storing session on the client ( server ) side the client will authenticate ( by providing credentials; username & password for simple use case ), then the server will check the authentication and send a token if credentials are valides ( a string ), so when the client will request a resource on the server he should provide this token, then the server will validate this token and serve the response if the token is valid

Comment: check this [article](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java)

Comment: thank you for explanation and link :)

Comment: you welcome my friend ! also don't forget to post an edit for your Q so that other people can have an idea about the solution ;) if they're facing the same issue